# Harry Potter fanfiction where Voldemort traps Harry in a casket and covers it in the Invisibility Cloak: saved by Snape?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

From what I remember Voldemort discovers Harry is a Horcrux, locks him away in a casket (in a world of ice) and gets discovered by Snape.

Harry is then left traumatised and it's a long road to recovery while Voldemort is still at large. I think he gains Slytherin's locket and gets ensnared by Tom Riddle.

One notable line is Snape having the ability to fly.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337), and [these ones on fanfic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're thinking of [Mine](https://archiveofourown.org/works/17604014/chapters/41498540) by ObsidianPen. It's Part 1 of the Haunted and Hunted series.

> Snow and ice everywhere, flat and endless—as far as the eye could see, a barren world of snow.
>
> Where was he? If he had to hazard a guess, Harry would say this was the landscape of Antarctica

...

> He appeared to be in some sort of invisible, clear container, floating a few feet above the flat ground below.

...

> He came to a horrible, unwanted conclusion. The word floated to the forefront of his mind, unbidden—
>
> Coffin.
>
> Hysterical panic like Harry had never known seized him.
>
> He was in a magical, glass coffin, in a world that looked as though a human being had never once set foot in it.